# Is there a practical way to use JavaScript/HTML as a proxy for acoustic echo cancellation in ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, microphone

I know there's some AEC in ActionScript 3.0 these days, particularly with the `Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone()` function and the related configurations.  But what if that's not good enough?  There are still issues that could hopefully be eliminated.  I've been doing some hunting around on the Internet, and about all I've found people saying is that this really is the best AS3 can do with acoustic echo cancellation, and in many places, people are trying to advise others to just tell their customers to go get better sound equipment.

If this just really isn't going to work out in AS3, is there a nice, practical way to use JavaScript/HTML in an HTML wrapper as a proxy for the microphone that will facilitate this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer... Using AS3, no.

You cannot manipulate the media before it hits the FlashPlayer neither you can change it after it is processed.

Although you have two possible choices:

- Process the sound sent from Flash Player on the server side and try to improve it there.
- Change the technology from Flash to [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) and try the acoustic echo cancellation provided by the browsers. It will only work on Chrome and Firefox for now, but it may be the future replacement of Flash. If you still don't like the level of cancellation, you can also process it on the server side because, just like Flash, you cannot mess with the stream on the client side in real-time.